# Pytorch RNN error: RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions got 1

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to train an RNN based off the code [here](https://blog.floydhub.com/a-beginners-guide-on-recurrent-neural-networks-with-pytorch/)

I also found two similar posts, but was not able to extrapolate from them what I should do to fix my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305941/pytorch-path-generation-with-rnn-confusion-with-input-output-hidden-and-batc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131870/pytorch-gru-error-runtimeerror-size-mismatch-m1-1600-x-3-m2-50-x-20)

The error is pretty easy to interpret, the model is expecting 3 dimensions, but I am only giving it 1. However, I do not know where to fix the issue.  I know that a good stack post is to include data, but I am not sure how to include example tensors in the post.  Apologies.

My input are 300d word embeddings and my output are one hot encoded vectors of length 11, where the model makes a classification choice in each of the 11 output dimensions.

**I will start with the dataloader then go from there with the code.**

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dat, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.dat = dat

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        label = self.labels[idx]
        dat = self.dat[idx]
        sample = {"Sample": dat, "Class": label}
        return sample
```

**I define my vanilla RNN as follows.**

```
class VanillaRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_dim, n_layers):
        super(VanillaRNN, self).__init__()

        # Defining some parameters
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers

        #Defining the layers
        # RNN Layer
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_dim, n_layers, batch_first=True)   
        # Fully connected layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_size)
    
    def forward(self, inputs):
        
        batch_size = inputs.size(0)

        # Initializing hidden state for first input using method defined below
        hidden = self.init_hidden(batch_size)

        # Passing in the input and hidden state into the model and obtaining outputs
        out, hidden = self.rnn(inputs, hidden)
        
        # Reshaping the outputs such that it can be fit into the fully connected layer
        out = out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_dim)
        out = self.fc(out)
        
        return out, hidden
    
    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        # This method generates the first hidden state of zeros which we'll use in the forward pass
        # We'll send the tensor holding the hidden state to the device we specified earlier as well
        hidden = torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim)
        return hidden
```

**and my training loop as follows**

```
def plot_train_val(x, train, val, train_label,
                   val_label, title, y_label,
                   color):

  plt.plot(x, train, label=train_label, color=color)
  plt.plot(x, val, label=val_label, color=color, linestyle='--')
  plt.legend(loc='lower right')
  plt.xlabel('epoch')
  plt.ylabel(y_label)
  plt.title(title)


def count_parameters(model):
  parameters = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
  return parameters


def init_weights(m):
  if type(m) in (nn.Linear, nn.Conv1d):
    nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight)



# Training functioN
def train(model, device, train_loader, valid_loader, epochs, learning_rate):

  criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
  
  train_loss, validation_loss = [], []
  train_acc, validation_acc = [], []

  for epoch in range(epochs):
    #train
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.
    correct, total = 0, 0
    steps = 0
    for idx, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
      text = batch["Sample"].to(device)
      target = batch['Class'].to(device)
      target = torch.autograd.Variable(target).long()
      text, target = text.to(device), target.to(device)
      # add micro for coding training loop
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      output, hideden = model(text)
      print(output.shape, target.shape, target.view(-1).shape)
      loss = criterion(output, target.view(-1))
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
      steps += 1
      running_loss += loss.item()

      # get accuracy
      _, predicted = torch.max(output, 1)
      print(predicted)
      #predicted = torch.round(output.squeeze())
      total += target.size(0)
      correct += (predicted == target).sum().item()

    train_loss.append(running_loss/len(train_loader))
    train_acc.append(correct/total)

    print(f'Epoch: {epoch + 1}, '
          f'Training Loss: {running_loss/len(train_loader):.4f}, '
          f'Training Accuracy: {100*correct/total: .2f}%')

    # evaluate on validation data
    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0.
    correct, total = 0, 0

    with torch.no_grad():
      for idx, batch in enumerate(valid_loader):
        text = batch["Sample"].to(device)
        print(type(text), text.shape)
        target = batch['Class'].to(device)
        target = torch.autograd.Variable(target).long()
        text, target = text.to(device), target.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(text)
        
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        running_loss += loss.item()

        # get accuracy
        _, predicted = torch.max(output, 1)
        #predicted = torch.round(output.squeeze())
        total += target.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == target).sum().item()

    validation_loss.append(running_loss/len(valid_loader))
    validation_acc.append(correct/total)

    print (f'Validation Loss: {running_loss/len(valid_loader):.4f}, '
           f'Validation Accuracy: {100*correct/total: .2f}%')

  return train_loss, train_acc, validation_loss, validation_acc
```

**When I run the model with the following, I get the error provided below.  Thanks in advance for any help.**

```
# Model hyperparamters
#vocab_size = len(word_array)
learning_rate = 1e-3
output_size = 11
input_size = 300
epochs = 10
hidden_dim = 100
n_layers = 2

# Initialize model, training and testing
set_seed(SEED)
vanilla_rnn_model = VanillaRNN(input_size, output_size, hidden_dim, n_layers)

#vanilla_rnn_model = VanillaRNN(output_size, input_size, RNN_size, fc_size, DEVICE)
vanilla_rnn_model.to(DEVICE)

vanilla_rnn_start_time = time.time()
vanilla_train_loss, vanilla_train_acc, vanilla_validation_loss, vanilla_validation_acc = train(vanilla_rnn_model,
                                                                                               DEVICE,
                                                                                               train_loader,
                                                                                               valid_loader,
                                                                                               epochs = epochs,
                                                                                               learning_rate = learning_rate)
```

**The error :(**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-bfd2f8f3456f> in <module>()
     19                                                                                                valid_loader,
     20                                                                                                epochs = epochs,
---> 21                                                                                                learning_rate = learning_rate)
     22 print("--- Time taken to train = %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - vanilla_rnn_start_time))
     23 #test_accuracy = test(vanilla_rnn_model, DEVICE, test_iter)

6 frames
<ipython-input-30-db1fa6c8b625> in train(model, device, train_loader, valid_loader, epochs, learning_rate)
     45       # add micro for coding training loop
     46       optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 47       output, hideden = model(text)
     48       print(output.shape, target.shape, target.view(-1).shape)
     49       loss = criterion(output, target.view(-1))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-26-c34b90b3cbc3> in forward(self, x)
     21 
     22         # Passing in the input and hidden state into the model and obtaining outputs
---> 23         out, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)
     24 
     25         # Reshaping the outputs such that it can be fit into the fully connected layer

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    263         assert hx is not None
    264         input = cast(Tensor, input)
--> 265         self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
    266         _impl = _rnn_impls[self.mode]
    267         if batch_sizes is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in check_forward_args(self, input, hidden, batch_sizes)
    227 
    228     def check_forward_args(self, input: Tensor, hidden: Tensor, batch_sizes: Optional[Tensor]):
--> 229         self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
    230         expected_hidden_size = self.get_expected_hidden_size(input, batch_sizes)
    231 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in check_input(self, input, batch_sizes)
    201             raise RuntimeError(
    202                 'input must have {} dimensions, got {}'.format(
--> 203                     expected_input_dim, input.dim()))
    204         if self.input_size != input.size(-1):
    205             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 1
```

Comment: Please, update with the full error traceback.

Comment: @Berriel Just updated the OP to contain that information.  Thanks!

Comment: What's the shape of `text` before `model(text)`? BTW, this traceback is truncated by IPython :(

Comment: I pasted the full error message, sorry about that.

Comment: @Berriel the size of text is: torch.Size([300]) and the size of target is torch.Size([11])

Comment: Are you sure `text` is only `[300]`? I see you're using a dataloader... I would expected at least an additional batch dimension. What is the shape of `self.dat` in your dataset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236877/discussion-between-aswiderski-and-berriel).

Comment: Stack asked me to move to a chat, i started it, but if this is easier here my first response was "The text.shape is what I get when I printed out from the training function. My colab just timed out so I am having to reload a bunch of stuff before I can answer your next question!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to wrap your dataset in a proper dataloader, and you can do something like this:

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# [...]

# define a batch_size, I'll use 4 as an example
batch_size = 4

train_dset = CustomDataset(X2, y)  # your current code (change train_loader to train_dset)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True))
```

At this point, `text` now should be `[4, 300]`.

Then, you said the your sequence length is equal to 1. To fix the error, you can add the length dimension using `unsqueeze`:

```py
# [...]
output, hideden = model(text.unsqueeze(1))
# [...]
```

Now, `text` should be `[4, 1, 300]`, and here you have the 3 dimensions the RNN forward call is [expecting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html) (your RNN has `batch_first=True`):

> **input**: tensor of shape `(L, N, H_in)` when `batch_first=False` or `(N, L, H_in)` when `batch_first=True` containing the features of the input sequence. (...)

Comment: Thanks @Berriel for your patience and thoughtful feedback!